# extract tuple items from list without accessing index

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the tuple items which consist of another embedded tuple without using the index.

```
items = [(('a', 'b'), 'a'), (('a', 'b'), 'b'), (('a', 'b'), 'c'), (('a', 'b'), 'd')]

# Currently accessing using index
for xy,z in items:
    print(xy[0],xy[1],z)

# Trying without index but getting error
for x, y, z in items:
    print(x,y,z)

for item in items:
    x, y, z = item
    print(x,y,z)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to wrap the nested tuple to have an extra layer of unpacking:

```
for (x, y), z in items:
    print(x,y,z)
```

Note how `(x, y)` causes the inner tuple to be unpacked.

Answer (score 2):

Look your error message carefully.
It said,

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

This means, **Python coudln't match the number of variables with the number of assignments.**
For example, if you run this code

```py
a, b = "e"
```

There is a similar error.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Because "e" is a string, which is the array with length 1.
So if you use a, b to assign values, Python expects that two values are needed.
But we put one value, length 1 array, "e"

You can track your problem by simplifying iteration code.

```py
for x in items:
  print(x)
```

This code unpacks the most outer tuple in the list.

```
(('a', 'b'), 'a')
(('a', 'b'), 'b')
(('a', 'b'), 'c')
(('a', 'b'), 'd')
```

If you try do this

```py
for x, y in items:
  print(x, y)
```

The result will be

```
('a', 'b') a
('a', 'b') b
('a', 'b') c
('a', 'b') d
```

In this case, x is ('a', 'b') and y is from a to d, which is the second element of the tuple.
The variable x is not single value but a tuple.
So you have to let Python know that.
**"Hey, the first element('a', 'b') of the each tuple(('a', 'b'), a) in the list is a tuple!"**
That's why other answers tell you,

```py
for (x, y), z in items:
  print(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
items = [(("a", "b"), "a"), (("a", "b"), "b"), (("a", "b"), "c"), (("a", "b"), "d")]

for (x, y), z in items:
    print(x, y, z)
```

Prints:

```
a b a
a b b
a b c
a b d
```